# Managing slices with mutex for performance in golang

Tags: go, memory, mutex

I have a struct as follows.

```
type User struct {
    Mutex sync.RWMutex
    Username string
    Stuff map[string]string
}
```

I also have the following globally.

```
var MyUsers []User
var UserMutex sync.RWMutex
```

Since my application is accessing the `MyUsers` slice thousands of times per second, I thought this would be the best way to manage performance. If I want to modify a separate `MyUsers` element, then I lock that specific element with:

```
MyUsers[x].Mutex.Lock()
```

Then perform any modifications and unlock it.

My question is, Is this a safe way of doing this? I have the normal global `UserMutex` to lock the slice only when appending to the slice... But when appending to a slice, are all existing elements moved in memory?

What happens if one thread appends to the slice at the same time whilst another thread is modifying an element? Can this happen in the setup above?

Could I potentially allocate a big enough slice using `make()` so that any `append()`'s won't affect the place in memory?

Comment: Never, literally never ever make a sync.WhateverMutex a field of a struct. Always use a *sync.WahteverMutex because you **must** **not** copy a sync.Mutex. And during append to a slice elements may be copied. Also: You must prevent _all_ modifications while appending, so individual protection must include a read lock on MyUsers. Probably you should redesign, but hard to tell.

Comment: @Volker: Mutex values are extremely common and idiomatic, both embedded and as a named field. Also, `go vet` warns about copying mutex values if you don't use a pointer to the struct. I don't think there's actually a single `*sync.Mutex` field in the entire std library.

Comment: @JimB Yes, if the struct containing the Mutex is always passed via a pointer this is fine. OP's `var MyUsers []User` and `var MyUsers []User`do not fall under this category. I admit the advise was too strong.

Comment: @Volker: yes, the `[]User` type is the issue here, though literally writing _any_ test at all will fail when the mutex is copied, so I would hope one never gets very far with that.

Answer (score 3):

As you already noticed, it is not safe cause `append` might need to allocate a new array if capacity is exceeded, and this will cause the elements to be copied into the new array.

However, you could store pointers in your `MyUsers` slice instead of values:

```
var MyUsers []*User
```

If you do this, then there wouldn't be an issue when allocating a new array since the pointers will be moved around, but still pointing to the same underlying `User` structs.

Also, as noted in the comments, it'd be better to use a pointer to the `Mutex` in the `User` struct just in case:

```
Mutex *sync.RWMutex
```

But it'd be even better if you design your code so that you never make a copy of a `User` object and you always pass the pointers around.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

I have changed the slice to store pointers instead of values, I have also changed the mutex to be a pointer inside the struct.

This post and everyones comments above (thanks Jim and Volker also) has made me understand and also taught me that i should really think about what types to use during situations like these, rather then just rushing and writing out fields without actually thinking about each specific field and what ill be doing with it.